# cmath error on MacOS c++17: call to abs ambiguous

Tags: c++, macos, c++17

Having this error using c++17 on Mac OS.
As far as I can tell, code is correct and should work fine (compiles without issue w/ g++ and clang++ on linux).
Also, as far as I can tell, the current default mac version of clang [10.0.1] should support c++17 (full version info printout below).

So, my question is: is this actually a bug in my code, but it works by fluke on linux? Or is it an issue with MacOS clang e.g., not full c++17 implementation?

From cppref:
Defined in header  (since C++17): 
`int abs( int n );`
Other c++17 features seem to work completely fine.

```
#include <cmath>
// #include <cstdlib> //works if included
int main() {
  int i = 1;
  // return std::abs(1); // Works fine
  return std::abs(i); // Fails
}
```

Compile with:
`clang++ -std=c++17 test.cpp`

Get this error:

```
test.cpp:7:10: error: call to 'abs' is ambiguous
  return std::abs(i);
         ^~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h:761:1: note:
      candidate function
abs(float __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return ::fabsf(__lcpp_x);}
^
(... etc.)
1 error generated.
```

If you `#include <cstdlib>`, it works without error.
using `-std=gnu++17` or `-std=c++1z` doesn't remove the problem either.
In the actual code (which is obviously more complex than the above, and actually uses c++17 features), the error happens depending on the *order* of my include files.
I can't replicate that in the simple example, but I assume it boils down to calling the `cstdlib` version instead of the `cmath` version.

Currently, my 'workaround' is to just put the header includes into the order that works..but this is hardly a long-term solution.

Does anyone know the cause?

Version info (error not specific to this MacOS version, also happens on my students' laptops):

```
Bens-iMac:test ben$ clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [LWG Issue 2912](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2192)

This has been fixed in libc++ trunk. I don't know if Apple has shipped this fix yet. As you found, including `<cstdlib>` is a workaround.